# How can make an Xpath into a loop in python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

the next time i wanna click on this button using selenium the x path changes to

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

I wanna convert this into a for look in the range(1,5). I used the below code:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
string=str(l)
for i in string:
  button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div"+i)
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
  time.sleep(5)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[ because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having large xpaths like that are fragile and difficult to navigate. You would probably have more success with a smaller, more accurate xpath.

Addressing your issue:
If you look at your error `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[' is not a valid XPath expression.`
This is not truncated. This is the xpath you're looking for - You're ending it with an open square bracket so it's not valid.

Have a look at making this xpath string valid before you feed it into find_by.

*[edit - URL provided in the comments]*

Looking at the page provided, try:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='amscroll-load-button']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

It's a smaller xpath that goes right to the object without navigating the entire DOM.

When I run that xpath it always identifies just 1 object. Even if you click it and the page moves, wherever it moves still it still only identifies one.

If you want to use this, be aware there's an asynchronous page load when you click it. You'll also need a dynamic wait to let the data/page to load before you press it another time.
If you want to just see if it works, the lazy approach is to enter a few seconds of sleep/wait between the click commands.

If you want to know more about finding xpaths using devtools - have a look at [this](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/) resource. Few videos at 10 minutes each can save a lot of headache on how to get the right objects.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info - added some more detail to the answer :-)